# Wordpress Setting Custom URLs for login. Not Possible?

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I am not an expert for mod_rewrite, so I need a big time help. Here is the scenario:

Domain Name: *www.example.com*
Points To: `/www/public_html/`

I have a wordpress installation at:

```
/www/public_html/subfolder/
```

Now I have two htaccess files, lets call them `.h1` and `.h2` . I have managed upto now to do this:

When user types www.example.com they are taken to the wordpress homepage in the subdirectory (sweet). In fact everything is hunky-dory besides:

**MAIN PROBLEM:**

I want to create a custom login URL, say : www.example.com/mylogin

I am able to do the following by setting the following in my `.h2`

```
    RewriteRule ^mylogin$ wp-login.php
```

But when I use this URL, it taken me to the login screen but the url in the browser changes to http://example.com/subfolder/wp-login.php

I want the URL that is displayed when the login screen is presented to stay the same as before i.e. http://example.com/mylogin

More precisely, no subfolder name and no wp-login should be displayed. How do I achieve this? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Your solution doesn’t hide the default login url. It only adds an easier to remember url which redirects to the default url /wp-login.

Without the need for coding you can easily install the plugin [Custom Login and Admin URL’s](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/custom-login-and-admin-urls/) that fixes this weakness.

> **Caution:** This plugin have been tested on a new installation of WordPress and it worked fine. However, most free plugins are unsupported which means they sometimes conflict with other plugins depending on what you have installed. If you have any issues, login to cPanel or FTP and delete the plugin or contact your web hosting provider.

Another Security plugin for WordPress which you may want to take a look at is named [Better WP Security](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/better-wp-security/). This WordPress plugin offers security settings for WordPress login, registration and admin pages as well as many other anti hacking features to protect your site.

Comment: Hi, Sorry to say but neither of these two plugins do the job. Better WP Security is able to change the login URL but then the URL becomes: example.com/subfolder/mylogin. I'd like to just display example.com/mylogin